# Eclipse android sdk location on external hard drive

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

Is it possible to set your SDK location to your external hard drive without the drive letter?
I want to know this because i always have to switch the location every-time i switch to another computer.
[image]

Comment: Why are you switching pc.Just have a copy of android adt bundle.Every where you go just extract it and use it.Just take your code with you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid not sorry bro no can do because your eclipse will store this information in an XML file so its not really "programmable" it will always be a final value.

Comment: Now now don't get all sad and such, I'd try to put your adk and your eclipse on the same external HDD and make the reference with a static path.. maybe that'll work if that could help u

Comment: sorry, what is a static path and how do i do it?

Comment: Well I'm not 100% sure but just move your whole SDK folder to your external drive and open your eclipse from within the SDK -> Eclipse -> blah blah folder.. should work